# which is the better way to set NODE_ENV according your npm run

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have tried figure out how set my NODE_ENV in nestjs according what i am doing, if run start in my local i expect NODE_ENV=development but if i run integration test then NODE_ENV=test. whats the best approach y pretend use cross-env and each npm run command use cross-env e.g "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node index.js" and so on, i want to know what do you think and your experience.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't fully understand the question, but the way I set the environment variables (that is for node.js without nestjs on the IBM Cloud) is the following:

- On local, I have a vcap-local.json file. If this file exists, I either declare this as local or read the values from there.
- On the server, I either set the NODE_ENV variable directly in the app (there's some menu in the UI) or define the following commands in the deployment pipeline

```
cf set-env ${CF_APP} NODE_ENV test
cf restage
```

Does this answer your question somehow?

Comment: Any update please whether this addressed your issue, or what your actually issue was?